# Same javascript twice cause the conflict on the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an image slider and text slider on same page using same JavaScript. But some how it doesn't work properly as expected. I research some about this but only thing I found is to use no-conflict but it doesn't work either. When I exclude number-1 JavaScript code the number-2 slider works properly but when I include number 1 slider number 2 doesn't work properly. Is there a way I can avoid conflicting each other ? if so then how can I do this ? Here is my JavaScript code:

```
        <script> //number-2
            sliderInt = 1;
            sliderNext = 2;

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#slider > img#1').fadeIn(150);
                startSlider();
            })

            function startSlider() {

                count = $('#slider > img').size();

                loop = setInterval(function() {

                    if(sliderNext > count) {
                        sliderInt = 1;
                        sliderNext = 1;
                    }

                    $('#slider > img').fadeOut(150);
                    $('#slider > img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(150);

                    sliderInt = sliderNext;
                    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
                }, 3000);

            }

            function prev() {
                newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
                showSlide(newSlide);
            }

            function next() {
                newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
                showSlide(newSlide);
            }

            function stopLoop() {
                window.clearInterval(loop);
            }

            function showSlide(id) {

                stopLoop();

                if(id > count) {
                    id = 1;
                }else if(id < 1) {
                    id = count;
                }

                $('#slider > img').fadeOut(150);
                $('#slider > img#' + id).fadeIn(150);

                sliderInt = id;
                sliderNext = id + 1;

                startSlider();

            }

            $('#slider > img').hover(

                function() {
                    stopLoop();
                },
                function() {
                    startSlider();
                }

                // In the End of the line don't put comma ','

            );

        </script>

        <script> //number-1

            textsliderInt = 1;
            textsliderNext = 2;

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#slider_text > p#1').fadeIn(300)
                textsliderStart();
            })

            function textsliderStart() {
                count = $('#slider_text > p').size();

                loop = setInterval(function() {

                    if(textsliderNext > count) {
                        textsliderInt = 1;
                        textsliderNext = 1;
                    }

                    $('#slider_text > p').fadeOut(300);

                    $('#slider_text > p#' + textsliderNext).fadeIn(300);

                    textsliderInt = textsliderNext;
                    textsliderNext = textsliderNext + 1;
                }, 3000)
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `var` in front of `count = $('#slider_text > p').size();` and `loop = setInterval(function() {`

When you dont use var you declare count and loop at the global scope

Comment: I never though that would be so simple :) Thanks for the info @Dean North